# ¿Como acceder a un array apuntado por un campo en un struct en C?

Tags: array, c, punteros, struct

Si tengo los siguientes datos:

```
char array[10];
struct {
        char *a;
        char c;
} estrutura;

estrutura.a=array;
```

¿Cómo hago para acceder a un elemento de array desde estrutura, no directamente a array?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si para acceder a un elemento de `array` haces:

```
array[0] = 'c';
```

Cuando el array está dentro de una estructura, como `estructura.a`, el acceso queda así:

```
estructura.a[0] = 'c';
```

El acceso como ves es exactamente el mismo, solo hay que reemplazar `array` por la *ruta* del array

> Eferion gracias por responder pero mirá el array no esta dentro de la estructura. La estructutra contiene una puntero al array

Te equivocas. El array es, a todos los efectos, **un puntero**. Hay pocas diferencias entre arrays y punteros:

- En un array no puedes modificar la dirección a la que apunta
- Un array no se crea con `malloc` ni se puede liberar con `free`
- Los arrays se almacenan en la pila del programa, no usan memoria dinámica

Pero a la hora de la verdad, el compilador trata los arrays como punteros.

Así pues, sabemos que un puntero es una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria. `int array[10]` hace que `array` sea, a todos los efectos, un puntero de tipo `int` que apunta al primer elemento del array.

De hecho puedes verificar lo que te digo:

```
int main()
{
    int array[10];

    struct{
        char *a;
        char c;
    } estructura;

    estructura.a = array;

    printf("%x\n%x", (void*)array, (void*)estructura.a);
}
```

Si te fijas, verás que ambas variables apuntan a la misma región de memoria. Así es como funcionan los punteros

Comment: Eferion gracias por responder pero mirá el array no esta dentro de la estructura. La estructutra contiene una puntero al array.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es acceder a un **arreglo contenido dentro de una estructura**, te podría servir esto:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef char *Array[10];

typedef struct {
  Array array;
}Estructura;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  Estructura estructura;
  estructura.array[0] = "1";
  estructura.array[1] = "2";
  estructura.array[2] = "3";
  estructura.array[3] = "4";
  estructura.array[4] = "5";
  estructura.array[5] = "6";
  estructura.array[6] = "7";
  estructura.array[7] = "8";
  estructura.array[8] = "9";
  estructura.array[9] = "10";

  char *array[10];
  
  puts("\t ====== Datos array =======");
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("\t original: %s\n",estructura.array[i]);
    // asignamos el valor contenido en estructura.array a array
    array[i] = estructura.array[i];
    printf("\t copia: %s\n",array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

En esta parte asignamos el valor contenido en estructura.array a array:

```
array[i] = estructura.array[i];
```

La salida del programa es:

```
====== Datos array =======
     original: 1
     copia: 1
     original: 2
     copia: 2
     original: 3
     copia: 3
     original: 4
     copia: 4
     original: 5
     copia: 5
     original: 6
     copia: 6
     original: 7
     copia: 7
     original: 8
     copia: 8
     original: 9
     copia: 9
     original: 10
     copia: 10
```

Espero pueda servirte el ejemplo.

Comment: Fernando gracias por responder pero te respondo lo mismo que a Eferion. Mirá que el array no esta dentro de la estructura. La estructutra contiene una puntero al array.